# Hooking events with .on() with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hook events with the .on() method. The problem is I don't know how to get the object reference of the element on which the event take place. Maybe it's a midunderstanding of how the method really works... but I hope you can help.

Here's what I want to do:

When a file is selected, I want the path to be displayed in a div

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="file" class="finput" />
    <div class="fpath">No file!</div>
</div>
```

Here's my script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $this = $(this);

    $this.on("change", ".finput", {}, function() {
        var path = $(this).val()
        $(this).parents().children(".fpath").html(path.split("\\").pop());
    });
});
```

Something like that but that way it doesn't work.

Comment: what does your {} do ? I think it's not necessary so you could remove it !

Comment: What exactly does not work? Inside the `on` callback, `this` will refer to the element with class `finput`. **Your  code works fine** for me: http://jsfiddle.net/JjnmE/ But if yours is running in strict mode, `$(this)` will probably not work. Use `$(window)` instead.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g4k5d/ <-- works for me, must be a problem with your last line.

Comment: don´t forget to add `var ` on your $this, current you set $this in the global scope.

Comment: Use $(this).parent() (without the s).

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.finput').on("change", function() {
            var path = $(this).val()
            $(this).parents().children(".fpath").html(path.split("\\").pop());
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use on()? I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly.

```
$("#wrapper").on("change", ".finput", function(event){
     var path = $(this).val()
     $(this).parents().children(".fpath").html(path.split("\\").pop());

});
```

I haven't tested your code, but you need to attach the on() to the wrapper.

Can you just use change()?

```
$('.finput').change(function() {
 var path = $(this).val()
         $(this).parents().children(".fpath").html(path.split("\\").pop());
});
```

Comment: Method 'on' is nowadays a default method to handle events, look at this (from jquery.com):

The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(), .delegate(), and .live()

Comment: I may be wrong, since I haven't checked the source code, but I **think** that `.change()`, `.click()`, etc call `.on()` in the back end anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This should help. If you want to see when a file input changes, bind the event to it

```
  $("input[type='file']").on("change", function(e){
      var path = $(this).val();
  })
```

Comment: but the probleme is I add new finput after the dom is loaded and they re not bind to the event.. I want to mimic the .live() function

Comment: I modified your script to add that input dynamically to body tag, and it's still working for me.

You can check my snippet:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/196245/index19.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('body').on('change','input.finput', function() {
        var path = $(this).val()
        $(this).parent().children(".fpath").html(path.split("\\").pop());
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem is when I add new finput after the page is fully loaded, they are not attached to this event. That's why I used the .on() on document and the selector .finput as a parameter. What I understood of it, it's that by passing the selector ".input" as parameter, it will be evaluated at the moment the event is trigger. If I used .live() it works great, but it is depracated...

Comment: @maniak Ok, I understand. I updated the code to use delegation. I haven't tested it and I'm not sure if the change event on 'body' even makes sense.

Comment: @maniak Check out this simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6NcP/) I created to back up my last comment. If you add inputs dynamically, that handler should still work.

Comment: @maniak Updated the fiddle to demonstrate adding input dynamically: http://jsfiddle.net/M6NcP/1/. You have to actually select a file for change to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("change", ".finput", function() {
    $(".fpath").html(this.value.split("\\").pop());
});
```

This is a delegated event handler, meaning the .finput element has been inserted dynamically so we need to delegate the listening to a parent element.

If the .finput element is not inserted with Ajax and is present on page load, you should use something like this instead:

```
$(".finput").on("change", function() {
    $(".fpath").html(this.value.split("\\").pop());
});
```